# ScrollView padding cut off items

Tags: android

I try set padding on my ScrollView that contain LinearLayout, but i noticed that the first/last items cutting off.
Its seem like the ScrollView padding himself with the background, but don't notify a LinearLayout about that.

anyone know whay this happe?
Thanks..

My code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    tools:context="com.example.aviad.scrollview.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="40dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="#54d45f"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/conteiner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

    </ScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFXME.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `android:clipToPadding="false"` to your `LinearLayout`

Comment: @RicardoA. ah sorry I was at the Image and thought it is a ListView, but anyway, clipToPadding should help.

Comment: The behavior of the scrollview still same thing - the last item still cut off.